# What are the requirements of a suborbital trajectory, to ensure that a small payload burns up?

Tags: heat, reentry

How can one determine the required altitude/velocity/time from release required for a small spacecraft (1 to 10 kg) in a suborbital trajectory to ensure that it burns up as it re-enters the atmosphere?

Comment: By integrating the heat flux?

Answer (score 2):

**[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43768/after-what-speed-air-friction-starts-to-heat-up-an-object/43795#43795)** from Physics.SE is very relevant, I'll condense it's main features here.

The change in temperature of a body in the Earth's atmosphere is calculated using:

$$\frac{T_2}{T_1} = \left( 1+\frac{1}{2} \rho v^2 / P1 \right)^{2/7}$$

Assuming: Air temperature is $293 K$, and air density is $1.3 kg/m^3$, and pressure is $1 atm$.

Using this equation, you can plug in the required change in temperature to burn up your payload, and hence calculate the velocity required. With the velocity, you can reverse-engineer one out of infinite possible suborbital trajectories.

This particular question assumed a sphere of radius 1 meter, and asked about what speed would be required to increase it's temperature by $200º C$. Approximately, the answer was $2000 mph$ or around $900 m/s$. De-orbit speed from LEO is about *7 times that*.

My (uneducated) guess is that ***any* payload under $10 kg$ will burn up in the atmosphere if it re-enters from LEO at $7 km/s$**. It depends on the material and shape of the craft, as well as the size and density, but I still don't think any debris will survive the fall.

---

Sources and Further Reading:

[Physics.SE Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/43768/after-what-speed-air-friction-starts-to-heat-up-an-object/43795#43795) (heavily referenced)

[FAA 4.1.7 on Atmospheric Re-entry](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/designees_delegations/designee_types/ame/media/Section%20III.4.1.7%20Returning%20from%20Space.pdf).

['Re-entry Dynamics' : Dr. A. Pechev, University of Surrey.](http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/A.Pechev/lnlvp/AP-lec4.pdf)

Comment: The question is about sub-orbital trajectories, not LEO

Comment: I'm reasonably sure he means a suborbital trajectory *from LEO*, bringing the periapse below the surface. At least, that's how I interpreted it.