# Could a small enough femtosat/chipsat survive reentry without a heat shield?

Tags: artificial-satellite, reentry

Would it be possible to design a tiny satellite, such as a femtosatellite or a chipsat, with such a shape and ballistic coefficient, that it would survive reentry without a heat shield?  A bit like [this feathery question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9527/33) except that our chipsat wouldn't be made of quite the same material.  Somewhat of the opposite of [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9514/33).

Comment: I'm assuming you mean re-entry into Earth's orbit from LEO. The trick is to find a way to non-destructively dissipate 30 Joules of kinetic energy for every milligram of mass.

Comment: @uhoh I do.  Not sure how it could reentry from any higher orbit as there wouldn't be any drag, unless it's a highle elliptical orbit.

Comment: Temperature of a gas is a measure of the average kinetic energy of its molecules. This implies that the difference in velocity between the de-orbiting object and the ambient atmosphere (or the initial hypersonic airstream velocity) can be correlated to a temperature. The femtosatellite would have to be capable of withstanding that temperature in order to survive re-entry.

Comment: I suppose you are familiar with shooting stars :)

Comment: Small meteorites do not survive the entry into the atmosphere, larger ones do, at least partially. The ratio between surface and volume is getting worse for smaller particles, therefore a satellite has to be large enough to survive a reentryy at least partially.

Comment: @Uwe That sounds like an answer.  I must have been confused by dust particles which sometimes survive.

Comment: @Uwe Meteorites usually have insane velocities, though, AFAIK - typically much higher than LEO

Comment: About all meteorites arrive into the atmosphere from outside of the Earth system, on trajectories that bring them deep into the atmosphere immediately. It doesn't matter so much how many Joules you have to dissipate, as - how many Watts. So the reentry timescale is essential: put the chipsat into a trajectory that loses altitude slowly enough and it will be fine.

Comment: @SF. That sounds interesting, could you elaborate on that, perhaps in an answer?

Comment: @gerrit: Problem: that's not a freefall/orbital/suborbital trajectory. Your picosatellite, to survive without solid thick heat shielding, would need to have very lightweight *wings.* At near-orbital speeds you need very little lift - and extreme speed can give a plenty of lift, even with very low air pressure. That way you may descend from LEO altitudes for a long time, dissipating heat slowly through radiation and keeping lift, drag, pressure, heating and cooling in balance. But the timescale of such descent trajectory is *weeks*.

Comment: @SF. Cool, so the satellite slowly turns into a glider!  That fits within my question, though.  I did not have a requirement that our chipsat would be falling vertically down.  I wonder if turbulence wouldn't rip those wings apart before we are slow enough to not need them anymore, although fortunately there's not a lot of turbulence high up.  Hmm.

Comment: @gerrit: either it's a glider or a brick of ablator and thermal shielding, one of the two. If you consider it falling vertically down, from LEO altitude, not moving "sideways" relative to Earth surface, the situation is much better as you don't have nearly as much velocity to lose. A small parachute should be all it needs. But how would it arrive into that situation in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

A correctly prepared (shielded) nanosat could survive the reentry.

A satellite the scale of cubesat around Kármán Line would experience about 1 kilowatt of heating. This is not what a cubesat electronics can survive - but this is something a layer of aerogel can stop from conducting in, a mirror-coated foil from radiating in, and a few centimeters of light ablator to dissipate for a couple minutes. So if you package your femtosat of, say, 10cm^3 in a cubesat form factor (1000cm^3) of lightweight thermal shielding, it should survive just fine.

Locating it on the ground after reentry is an entirely different matter...

Comment: What about balsa wood, I guess four centimeters at each side should do it.

Comment: @Uwe: I don't know, but I believe cohesion is important; the ablator must ablate, not get ripped apart. TLA is a corkwood based ablator, really light, and probably more mechanically durable than balsa wood. The pieces of balsa wood I had in my hands, you could literally grind/smash it with your fingers.

Comment: Shielding is not necessary https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/docs/p390.pdf

Answer (score -3):

I think it's an interesting question,
The way I see it is your satellite stays in orbit because of it's high speed but it also burns up because of it's high speed. If you can get it traveling slow enough by the time it reaches the atmosphere you should be able to use atmospheric drag without burning up. So you would need a way to slow it between the orbit height and speed and the atmosphere.

I think it could be interesting do the math for trying to slow a chipsat by using a collection of tethers using drag generated by geomagnetically induced current, so using the magnetic field of the earth to slow down before hitting the atmosphere. But I wouldn't know where to begin with running those sorts of calculations.

Comment: That's not an answer, but a new question. Feel free to create a new question for this.